# erro ao usar int no input em python

Tags: python, input, int

Opa. Eu estou fazendo um projeto de RPG por texto em Python, mas estou com alguns problemas quando vou fazer a parte para o usuário escolher o personagem.
Aqui abaixo está o código completo:

```
pers = [
    'Berserk', 'Barbáro',
    'Mago', 'Bruxo',
    'Paladino', 'Cavaleiro',
    'Druida', 'Xamã',
    'Ninja', 'Assasino'
    ]

print(f'1-{pers[0]} 2-{pers[1]} 3-{pers[2]} 4-{pers[3]} 5-{pers[4]} 6-{pers[5]} 7-{pers[6]} 8-{pers[7]} 9-{pers[8]} 10-{pers[9]}')  # PERSONAGENS

escolha_personagem = int(input('qual personagem você escolhe?: '))

personagem_escolhido = 0
while personagem_escolhido == 0:
    if escolha_personagem == 1:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[0]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 2:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[1]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 3:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[2]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 4:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[3]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 5:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[4]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 6:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[5]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 7:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[6]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 8:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[7]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 9:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[8]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif escolha_personagem == 10:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[9]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1

    elif personagem_escolhido == str:
        print('erro!')
```

Só que mesmo assim, ele dá erro quando eu coloco uma str, algo que não deveria ocorrer por conta do último elif. O erro quando executo:

```
1-Berserk 2-Barbáro 3-Mago 4-Bruxo 5-Paladino 6-Cavaleiro 7-Druida 8-Xamã 9-Ninja 10-Assasino
qual personagem você escolhe?: a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adrian\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\RPG\rpg projeto.py", line 43, in <module>
    escolha_personagem = int(input('qual personagem você escolhe?: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Alguém pode por favor me ajudar?

Comment: Aqui `escolha_personagem = int(input('qual personagem você escolhe?: '))` você deve tratar a entrada antes de converter para inteiro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*algo que não deveria ocorrer por conta do último elif*"

Não, o último `elif` não faz sentido, por dois motivos:

1. `personagem_escolhido == str` está comparando `personagem_escolhido` com a classe `str`. Este código não está vendo se o tipo da variável é `str`, na verdade está vendo se a variável **é a própria classe** `str`. Para ver se uma variável é de determinado tipo, deve-se usar [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) (mas isso não serviria para o seu caso por causa do próximo motivo)
2. Ao fazer `escolha_personagem = int(...)`, você já converteu o valor para inteiro. Ou seja, se a conversão deu certo, o tipo da variável já é `int`. Por isso não faz sentido verificar se ela é uma string. Não é, nunca foi. Se a conversão não dá certo, ele lança um `ValueError` (que é o que ocorreu quando você digitou "a"), então para verificar isso deve-se usar um bloco `try`/`except`

E também dá para simplificar esse monte de `if` e outros detalhes do código (se você digita, por exemplo, `40`, ele entra em *loop*). Ficaria assim:

```py
pers = [ 'Berserk', 'Barbáro', 'Mago', 'Bruxo', 'Paladino', 'Cavaleiro', 'Druida', 'Xamã', 'Ninja', 'Assasino' ]

while True:
    try:
        # em vez de escrever um a um, junte todos em uma única string
        print(' '.join(f'{i + 1}-{p}' for i, p in enumerate(pers)))
        # já subtrai 1 para obter o respectivo índice da lista
        escolha_personagem = int(input('qual personagem você escolhe?: ')) - 1
        if 0 <= escolha_personagem < len(pers):
            print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[escolha_personagem]}!')
            break # sai do while
        else:
            # número fora do intervalo válido
            print(f'Digite um número entre 1 e {len(pers)}')
    except ValueError: # se não digitar número, lança ValueError
        print('Digite um número')
```

Não só fica mais simples, como continua funcionando se você mudar a lista de personagens. Por exemplo, se adicionar ou remover personagens, você teria que mudar o `print` e os `elif`'s, já usando o código acima, não precisa mudar nada no `while` que ele continua funcionando.

Answer (score -1):

Removi o tratamento de inteiro no input, fazendo isso você pode usar o isnumeric() que verifica se a string é formado por números e rotorna True ou False [Documentação](https://docs-python-org.translate.goog/3/library/stdtypes.html?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=pt&_x_tr_hl=pt-BR&_x_tr_pto=op,sc) depois criei um if com isnumeric se for verdadeiro converto outra variavel para int e executo seu código, se não ele printa um aviso, se digitar algum outro numero que não seja os que vc pediu ele para o loop e printa uma mensagem de valor errado...segue o código:

```
      escolha_personagem = input('qual personagem você escolhe?: ')
if escolha_personagem.isnumeric() == True:
    personagem = int(escolha_personagem)
    personagem_escolhido = 0
    while personagem_escolhido == 0:


    if personagem == 1:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[0]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 2:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[1]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 3:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[2]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 4:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[3]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 5:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[4]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 6:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[5]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 7:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[6]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 8:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[7]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 9:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[8]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    elif personagem == 10:
        print(f'Ok! Seu personagem é {pers[9]}!')
        personagem_escolhido += 1
    else:
        print('Voce digitou valor errado,\n digite entre 1 e 10')
        break
 else:
     print('\n           ATENÇÃO \n escolha um numero entre 1 e 10')
```